# How to create a leaderboard as a database

Tags: python, sql, database, leaderboard

I need to create a database which is a top 5 leaderboard, however, what I tried didn't work - it brought up many different errors (code below):

```
import sqlite3

winner_name = input("Name: ")
winner_score = input("Score: ")

db = sqlite3.connect('C:\Users\user\Desktop\WORK\CS\NEA\Python')

c = db.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE Leaderboard
(Place,text,
Name, text,
Score, text)
""")

c.execute("""INSERT INTO Leaderboard
             VALUES ("1",winner_name,winner_score)""")

db.commit()
c.execute('SELECT * FROM Leaderboard')
row = c.fetchone()
print(row)
db.close()
```

Problems:

1. The 4th line beginning "db = " comes up with an error on the brackets. I initially thought it had to do with the fact that I am trying to make a database and the program got confused, however, I am not sure.
2. On the line about halfway through beginning "VALUES", I want to make winner_name and winner_score the variable from the start of the code, but I am not sure if I have done it right or wrong (it is highlighted green like speech not black).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You wrote `INESRT`, not `INSERT`. Is that in any way related to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look on next things

1. [sqlite3.connect](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) should receive db file name , for example `example.db` (not a folder as in your case)
2. creating database have a [next syntax](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-create-table/), in your case comma is unnecessary between `Place` and`text`:
   `Place,next` (wrong) -> `Place text` (correct)
3. in inserting into table line it needs to pass values (in your case you are passing string):

```py
c.execute(f"""INSERT INTO Leaderboard
             VALUES ("1","{winner_name}",{winner_score})""")
```

(*make a notice to put quotes `"` for winner_name, because db awaiting text for this value*)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @AmanH vote-up would be enough ))) You are welcome :)

Comment: I'm sorry I have tried to upvote this both now and when I saw it, however, the website sends a message about not having 15 reputation and that it has been recorded. I did add a "accepted comment" tick.